# Building Docker image for Node application using Yarn dependency

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I am trying to build a docker image for a node application that uses yarn to install dependencies. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
 FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app
CMD npm run develop
EXPOSE 8000
```

Every thing runs well when I run yarn install on my local machine but when I do a docker build, I get this error that blocks for ever.

```
**docker build -t  rs  .**
Sending build context to Docker daemon  219.1MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:7
 ---> d9aed20b68a4
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /reason
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe51a1860989
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json /reason
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b0e136ee6eeb
Step 4/7 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Running in e273f8cf1f3e
yarn install v0.24.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "glamor" that matches "next"
? Please choose a version of "glamor" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
❯ 2.20.40
  2.20.39
  2.20.38
  2.20.37
  2.20.36
  2.20.35
  2.20.34
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)warning glamor@3.0.0-3: abandoned, please use v2 instead
warning gatsby-plugin-glamor > glamor-inline@1.0.5: use glamor/inline instead
warning gatsby-plugin-glamor > glamor-react > glamor@3.0.0-3: abandoned, please use v2 instead
warning gatsby-plugin-glamor > glamor-server > glamor@3.0.0-3: abandoned, please use v2 instead
warning gatsby > babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now:
```

please read babeljs.io/env to update!

The console remains in this stage for ever. How can I fix this please.

Comment: this looks more like issue with the packages that you are using. Try installing without docker. Just do a regular install on your machine (npm install) and see what happens. look for that particular module (and the version number)  on npmjs.org.

Comment: how areyou running your application without docker, npm run develop? if so change your CMD line like this "CMD ["npm", "run", "develop"] "

Answer (score 12):

You should first run yarn install to generate a yarn lockfile (**yarn.lock**) before building the image. Then make sure to copy it along with the package.json. Your dockerfile should look like this :

```
FROM node:7 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json /app 
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN yarn install 
COPY . /app 
CMD npm run develop 
EXPOSE 8000
```

With this all dependencies should install successfully when building your image

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now the image builds successfully but I'm unable to run it. When I do a docker run, it shows my site is running at localhost:8000 but when I go to the browser, nothing is seen. It says Safari can't connect to server mean while when I do a normal run with **npm run develop** everything works fine and I can see my site. What can be the problem here?

Comment: You need to make sure of two things. 1) That you are exposing 8000 with for example  docker run  -p 8000:8000 myimage 2) The dev server is running on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost instead of localhost just to make sure it will work as expected

Comment: to reduce the image size use alpine, you need to clean yar. check my answer

Answer (score 8):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:6.9.5-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code
RUN npm install -g -s --no-progress yarn && \
    yarn && \
    yarn run build && \
    yarn cache clean
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  sample-app:
    image: sample-node-yarn-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

**Create docker image**

```
docker build -t sample-node-app .
```

**RUN**

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Why do you need docker compose for a single image?

Comment: i don't think this will be a big mess, to easy our joob, run command is reduced to "docker-compose up" and "docker-compose down"

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the above answers by using a predefined yarn docker image. We are assuming here this image is only for development purpose. For production mode, you should only consider the minimum binaries, such as node.

```
FROM gmolaire/yarn:1.22.4_12.18.3-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /usr/local/app
ADD . .

RUN yarn install && \
    yarn build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "run", "develop" ]
```