# issue for dockerizing nodejs app with yarn

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to dockerize my simple nodejs app with yarn. Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk upgrade --update

FROM node:8

WORKDIR /apps/myapp

COPY . /apps/myapp

COPY package*.json /apps/myapp

RUN yarn && \
    yarn run build

COPY yarn.lock /apps/myapp
```

When I run this dockerfile, i see this output.
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 60.16s.
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

I see 'Saved lockfile', but COPY fails with this error message.

Removing intermediate container d4975a5f1155
 ---> 12af3c2fd907
Step 9/9 : COPY yarn.lock /apps/myapp
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder042321912/yarn.lock: no such file or directory

Is there something wrong with my dockerfile?

Comment: That sounds like you don’t have a `yarn.lock` in your local source tree; you should probably make sure to commit it to source control alongside your `package.json` file.  (`COPY` there doesn’t make a lot of sense, since you’re copying the file in after the `yarn` step that would consume it; also the `COPY .` will copy everything from your local source tree into the image.)

Comment: Hope this would help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744180/building-docker-image-for-node-application-using-yarn-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Following [David Maze's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) comment, you may want to set your Dockerfile like this

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs yarn

WORKDIR /apps/myapp

COPY . /apps/myapp

RUN yarn && yarn run build
```